# promQL to grafana panel union on similar labels

Tags: variables, prometheus, grafana, promql

this is my promql to a variable in grafana graṕh

```
label_values({ index=~"xxx.*"},Operator)
```

result:

```
abc test
abc ultra
def test
def super
```

but i'd like to make the union of abc labels as abc and def labels as def

```
abc
def
```

does anybody knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Regex = /^([^ ]+) /
```